# Help identifying which set this bag is from? White plates and Technic panels and transparent red circle plates?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Can anyone help to identify the set that is shown in the photos?
They were in a bulk lot of LEGO - so no manuals, no box.

Thanks!
Dale

[image: bag with transparent red circle and blue cockpit cover]

Comment: Having a bag 4 implies a larger set so there should also be bags 1-3 and maybe 5 and up.  Do you have those too?  Or just bag 4?

Comment: Hi Chicks, I only have bags 3 and four (unopened). There may be some of the other parts in the bulk lot (already opened).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the transparent red [Plate, Round 4 x 4 with 2 x 2 Hole](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11833#T=C), white plates, and trans-blue [Windscreen](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=46413&idColor=14#T=C&C=14) this is set# 76028 [Darkseid Invasion](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76028-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from the Justice League series.

[image: Darkseid Invasion]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go through the lot and see if I can find the other pieces. I downloaded the instructions so will have a go at assembling the set.

Comment: My pleasure.  :)  Happy LEGOing.